# In PostgresSQL when is it best to use WHERE and when is it best to use CASE WHEN?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I don't really understand the difference between CASE WHEN and WHERE, can they be used to achieve the same thing? Will someone please clarify?

Thanks!

Comment: `CASE WHEN` is an expression to let you change or generate values for every row. `WHERE` changes which rows you get. They cannot be used to accomplish the same work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the difference between the two, you have to think of the classic structure of a SQL statement:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...;
```

For example, if you think of a table called "shirts" with 500 rows, let's start by selecting all 500 of them:

```
-- first example: all rows as stored
SELECT 
  name, 
  color, 
  size, 
  maker
FROM shirts
ORDER BY name;
```

Next, let's add a WHERE clause. This serves to limit the rows returned in the final result set to only those that match some specified criterion. For instance, you can say "WHERE color = 'white'" to return a smaller set of (say) 80 rows:

```
-- second example: only some rows
SELECT 
  name, 
  color, 
  size, 
  maker
FROM shirts
WHERE color = 'white'
ORDER BY name;
```

The CASE statement serves an entirely different function: it is normally part of the SELECT clause-- it cannot be a separate clause in its own right-- and serves to reformat the output you receive in some way. So with a case statement, you would still get all 500 rows back, but your results won't look the same as they did in my first example:

```
-- third example: all rows, but color field is tweaked
SELECT 
  name, 
  (CASE WHEN color = 'white' THEN 'white' ELSE 'other' END) AS tweaked_color,
  size, 
  maker
FROM shirts
ORDER BY name;
```

In my first example, you'd have seen various values for "color": "white", "black", "brown", "yellow", "red", etc. With this third example, you'll see 80 rows with "white" and 420 rows with "other".

Hope that helps clarify the difference.

P.S. please note that I've arranged the whitespace in my examples in a somewhat unusual way for clarity's sake; how your arrange the whitespace doesn't make any difference to the syntax. I also added a pair of unnecessary parentheses around the CASE statement to help add some visual clarity; those also would usually be omitted.